# Enter loop when specific key entered - Java

Tags: java

Hi I have some code for the Java console to do something when specific keys are pressed. The system inputs and stores the key as a string no bother and I can print it out to confirm it works. However the code never enters the conditional statement and instead jumps to the else every time. Here is the code:

```
Scanner MenuChoice = new Scanner(System.in);
    Products.MenuCode = MenuChoice.next();


                if(Products.MenuCode=="F")
                {
                //Run subprogram for finding a product.
                Find.main();    

                }

                else{
                System.out.println("F - Find a Product");
                 System.out.println("p - Purchase a Product");
                  System.out.println("Q - Quit");
                  Scanner MenuChoice2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                  Products.MenuCode = MenuChoice2.next();
                };
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

you can do this

```
Scanner MenuChoice = new Scanner(System.in);
Products.MenuCode = MenuChoice.next();


            if(Products.MenuCode.equals("F")) // use equals method 
            {
            //Run subprogram for finding a product.
            Find.main();    

            }

            else{
            System.out.println("F - Find a Product");
             System.out.println("p - Purchase a Product");
              System.out.println("Q - Quit");
              Scanner MenuChoice2 = new Scanner(System.in);
              Products.MenuCode = MenuChoice2.next();
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't compare Strings using == you have to use the equals methode.

The equals method works like this:

```
boolean b = string1.equals(string2);
```